# Phonegap Ajax Post to PHP live server not posting through IOS

Tags: html, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I see there are several posts on this issue, however none of the answers are very clear or are working for me.  I have a simple JQuery Post that works great in a browser, but doesn't post to the PHP page on the server through the native app on IOS.  Is there a handler I can add to make it work or is it a whitelist issue?  Either way is there a good resource or simple instructions to fix the issue?  See my code below.

```
    $(function() {
$('#RFQ, #sQuote, #sQuote1, #sQuote2, #sQuote3').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
                    $('#RFQ, #sQuote, #sQuote1, #sQuote2, #sQuote3').html( $("#formResponse").html() );

        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi! This could be a whitelist issue. Are all the action URLs of your forms external or local? If you have external URLs, did you made modifications to your file Cordova.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you modified your file `Cordova.plist` correctly to allow external access.

Open your file `Cordova.plist` and check that you made the following:

**1 -** Set `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `YES`

**2 -** Right click on `ExternalHosts` -> `Add Row`

**3 -** Set the `String` value of your new added row to `*`, so you should have your new line look like this:

```
Item0                String              *
```

Normally, you would replace `*` with the external URL you want provide access to. But, to make sure that the problem really comes from the whitelist, we will use `*`.

For more information about domain whitelist, check the online doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Hope this helps.

Let me know if this works for after modifying your `Cordova.plist` file as described above.

Comment: That all sounds good, but I am doing my build on the Phonegap cloud.  I don't think I have access to the Cordova.plist as it inserts the phonegap elements for you. Do I have to do a manual build?

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out.  It was a silly mistake, I didn't have the whole address of the live server in my form action.  Problem solved!